# Arrange fields differently for different size classes

Tags: swift, xcode8

I'm working on an app that can display on iPhone 4s. When the screen is displayed portrait, it looks fine.  When in landscape, the controls run past the bottom of the screen.  Here's an example of what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

I'd like to move the last switch and label up beside the first switch and label, but only for compact/compact.  The only way that I've been able to make this work is to add another switch that is only visible for compact/compact, hide the other one, and then hook it up to the same outlet and action as the first switch.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you worked with stack view?

Comment: look into size classes when creating your constraints in storyboard. You can set different constraints based on screen size.